# C: initialising global constants with external linkage

Tags: c, initialization, extern

I want to statically initialise a struct that will be visible from all files which include some header.

The actual intention is to run lists of functions specified at compile time, which is why I want to initialise statically. I'd like to put the lists where they belong, in the file in which they are declared or defined.

**Contrived example:**

general.h:

```
struct Widget { int (*a)(); };
```

foo.h:

```
int oof1(void);
int oof2(void);
```

foo.c:

```
#include "foo.h"

int oof1(void) { return 1; }
int oof2(void) { return 2; }

struct Widget foo_widgets[] = { {oof1}, {oof2} };
```

bar.c:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "baz.h"

struct Widget *foo_widgets;
struct Widget *baz_widgets;

struct WidgetsContainer {
    struct Widget *widget_list;
} wlists[] =
    {
        { foo_widgets },
        { baz_widgets }
    };

void usage(void) { ... ; process (wlists[i].widget_list); ... }
```

This obviously doesn't work because "the initialiser element is not constant" - This is because when the compiler is translating bar.c, it thinks it doesn't know the location of foo_widgets (or bar_widgets).

But since bar.c #includes foo.h anyway, it's always compiled alongside foo.c:

`gcc foo.c baz.c bar.c`

So I'm hoping there's a way of reflecting this in the source code.

I can't declare `foo_widgets` in foo.h, because then I wouldn't be able to initialise it without defining it multiple times (as foo.h is included in more than one file).

**Inelegant workaround**

foo.h:

```
...

Widget *get_foos(void) { return foo_widgets; }
```

bar.c:

```
...

struct Widget_lists {
    struct Widget (*widget_list)();
} wlist[] =
    {
        { get_foos },
        { get_bazes }
    };

void usage(void) { ...; process(wlist[i].widget_list()); ... }
```

**Is there a better way?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to have a global variable that you can reach anywhere ... To do so you have to declare it as an *external* variable in the appropriate header.

Here, it should be done as follows :

**In foo.h :**

```
/* ... */
int oof1(void);
int oof2(void);
extern int (*foo_widget)(void)[2];
```

**In foo.c :**

```
int (*foo_widget)(void)[2] = {{oof1}, {oof2}};
```

By doing so, when including "foo.h", the `foo_widget` variable will be known (and expected to be **defined** somewhere else - in foo.c here - ).

To be more precise ... *Any piece of code* that needs to make use of `foo_widget` must have the line `extern int (*foo_widget)(void)[2];` somewhere, be it in an included header (the smarter way) or just a line at the beginning of the *.c* file.

Of course, if you cannot know in advance the number of widgets you can have, you are likely to need a dynamic data structure such as a linked list or a tree (ordered and balanced if possible ;) ) to store them. The `extern` variable is likely to be a regular pointer dynamically allocated when needed. But the **definition** line is *still* needed, so in this case you might have something like `struct my_struct *pointer = NULL;` in the appropriate source file.

Note : I took the freedom to replace your `struct Widget` with a common function pointer to get the initialization simpler.

Comment: Thanks :-) Didn't realise you needed to specify the array size for both the declaration and the definition.
The struct was necessary for storing additional data associated with each function.

Comment: @user234461 of course the initialization can be done for struct members, it is just more _"tiresome"_, I leave you with that ;)